# What would be the fastest way to create a string of n chars in C

Tags: c, string

What would be the fastest/shortest way to create a string of repeating characters.

For instance, `n = 10, char = '*', resulting allocated string: **********`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [memset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6.aspx).

```
int n = 10;
char c = '*';

char* buf = malloc(n+1);
memset(buf, c, n);
buf[n] = '\0';

free(buf);
```

Answer (score 6):

`memset(buf, '*', 10); buf[10]=0;`

Replace `'*'` and `10` with the values you want, and if the length is not known in advance and could be large, use `buf=malloc(n+1);` to get your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *allocate(int c, size_t n)
{
    if(!c) return calloc(n + 1);
    char *s = malloc(n + 1);
    memset(s, c, n);
    s[n] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Honestly, why are you trying to do it fastest? Why not just do it, and then speed it up later if you need to?

Particularly, if you're only creating this to output it, you could just

```
void printtimes(int c, size_t n, FILE *f)
{
    while(n--) fputc(c, f);
}
```

Comment: Repeatedly using `fputc` is pretty slow. When I've needed padding like this, I typically fill a small buffer (64-256 bytes) with `memset` then repeatedly `fwrite` it, using a smaller length for the tail remainder. If nothing else, switch to `putc` or `putchar` so the implementation has a chance to replace it with a macro.

Comment: Actually it didn't come up to my mind memset(); I was thinking of using a for() loop, but thanks :)

Comment: @R.. - True. I was mostly just trying to show that the OP could optimize if this was meant for immediate output.